# How to run multiple command sequentially?

Tags: system, pantheon-terminal

I am new to elementary OS. I usually use windows. In windows we can create `batch` file which can make several command run at command prompt by single click. How to do this in elementary OS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make shell scripts to achieve this. A shell script usually starts with `#!/bin/bash`. Let's say you want to execute `sudo apt update` and `ls` but you don't want to type it every time. So a shell script for that is,

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update
ls
```

Save it with ".sh" extension and execute `sudo chmod +x file_name.sh` to give the file executable permission. Then you can execute the script by `./file_name.sh`.
Take a look here, described well in this answer at [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/223698/907048).

Comment: the link is not working may be

Comment: Please check again, link in my earlier comment is working correctly.